# How to have an image rotated to a random degree when webpage is loaded? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, random, image-rotation

I’m trying to create a small project that has the user guess the degree of rotation of an image and then gives a paragraph that tells the user how many degrees the image is rotated and how many degrees they are off. I tried setting the image's rotation to a random amount between 0 and 359 using Math.random() at line 2, and then using the transform style on the image outside of any function. I was hoping by setting the rotation outside of a function that it would occur as soon as the page is loaded but that is not working (I am new to coding). How can I fix this? Here’s my JS code:

```
let image = document.getElementById(`image`)
let rotation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359)
let degrees = document.getElementById(`degrees`)
let submitButton = document.getElementById(`submitButton`)
let difference
let rotationParagraph = document.getElementById(`rotationParagraph`)

image.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation.value}deg)`

submitButton.addEventListener(`click`, guessRotation)

function guessRotation() {
  difference = `Math.abs(${rotation.value} - ${degrees.value})`
  rotationParagraph.innerHTML = `Rotation is ${rotation.value}. You were off by ${difference.value}.`
}
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Guess the Rotation</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js" defer>

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Guess the Rotation</h1>

  <!-- image that will be rotated -->
  <div id="object">
    <image src="connection.jpg" width="200" style="transform: rotate" id="image">
  </div>

  <!-- side panel -->
  <div id="sidePanel">
    <p id="">How many degrees is the image rotated?</p>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="359" placeholder="0-359" id="degrees">
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <p id="rotationParagraph"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
#object, 
#sidePanel {
  /* puts the image and side panel side by side */
  display: inline-block;

  /* makes the image and side panel aligned at the top */
  vertical-align: top;
}

#image {
  /* gives dimensions and a border to the image */
  border: 1px solid black;

  /* puts empty space to the right of the box to separate it from the side panel */
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

I tried setting the image's rotation to a random amount between 0 and 359 using Math.random at line 2, and then using the transform style on the image outside of any function.

I tried adding the rotation in CSS using "rand(0, 359)deg" as the rotation amount and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
image.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation.value}deg)`
```

perhaps `.value` was a typo, but it needs to be deleted:

```
image.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
```

I've made a working snippet, with some extra styling to make the image container elongated and coloured so you can see the rotation. The angle is different for each reload, as you intended.

```js
let image = document.getElementById(`image`)
//let rotation = 90;
let rotation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 359)
let degrees = document.getElementById(`degrees`)
let submitButton = document.getElementById(`submitButton`)
let difference
let rotationParagraph = document.getElementById(`rotationParagraph`)

image.style.transform = `rotate(${rotation}deg)`;

submitButton.addEventListener(`click`, guessRotation)

function guessRotation() {
  difference = `Math.abs(${rotation.value} - ${degrees.value})`
  rotationParagraph.innerHTML = `Rotation is ${rotation.value}. You were off by ${difference.value}.`
}
```

```css
#object, 
#sidePanel {
  /* puts the image and side panel side by side */
  display: inline-block;

  /* makes the image and side panel aligned at the top */
  vertical-align: top;
}

#image {
  /* gives dimensions and a border to the image */
  border: 1px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 0.5;
  background: yellow;

  /* puts empty space to the right of the box to separate it from the side panel */
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Guess the Rotation</h1>

  <!-- image that will be rotated -->
  <div id="object">
    <image src="connection.jpg" width="50"  id="image">
  </div>

  <!-- side panel -->
  <div id="sidePanel">
    <p id="">How many degrees is the image rotated?</p>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="359" placeholder="0-359" id="degrees">
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <p id="rotationParagraph"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @dave. Do I only use .value on variables that are input by the user?

Comment: Yes, you would use `.value` to extract a value from a user entry object. So to read the value of your user `input` field, you make a reference to the field *object* : `const userInput=document.getElementById('degrees');` and extract its value using `.value` like this: `let userValue=userInput.value'`. This can also be achieved in one step using: `let userValue=document.getElementById('degrees').value` but it's worth knowing that shortcut is still making a (temporary) reference first to the html object and then to the value held by it.